# how to locate an item in a specific row and column in a verticaly-wrapped VariableSizedWrapGrid?

Tags: wpf, windows, xaml, gridview, windows-8

I want to locate an item in a specific row and column in the automatic-generated-vertical-wrapped-list of VariableSizedWrapGrid.
My view model exposes a collection and I want that the first item will be in the first row and column (I mean 0,0 - that's not a problem). Also I want that the second item in the collection to be located in the second column and in the first row (0,1), and I want the third item to be located in (1,1), below the second item...
and the rest items to be located in the rest of the free space.... 
I find that a problem because I don't know what will be the number of rows in this vertical-wrapped-adjustable Grid...

What do you suggest me to do?

Comment: You should tag your questions correctly to avoid confusion. Since Wpf doesn't have VariableSizedWrapGrid this question should be tagged  with xaml-rt. Consequently UniformGrid exists in wpf, but not in winrt.

Answer (score 0):

Using a [UniformGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid.aspx) with an [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx) should provide you the desired result. For example, if `List<string>` is the DataContext:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <-- set the desired number of columns and omit the number of rows -->
            <UniformGrid Columns="2" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Margin="2"
                    BorderBrush="Tomato"
                    BorderThickness="1">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```